How to count the total number of textlines in a table when the texts wrap inside a cell
Essentially, I am referring to this question I posted a couple years back. The query I posted in the first comment to the accepted answer still remains unresolved. It occurs to me that if the total number of lines of text be calculated, it'd solve the issue. Because, then I can replace \value{rowcount} with this new counter and things will fall in place automatically. Please help me how to achieve that.
EDIT:
Following is the code I am currently stuck with.
\documentclass[a5paper, twoside, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[cmyk, table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[margin=20mm, includehead, foot=4mm, marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {/Users/AaRBiTt/OneDrive/Documents/Salesian College/Logos} }
\def\mycolor{cyan}
\def\colour{magenta}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{cmbright}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{}{}{0pt}{\@gobble}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{}{}{0pt}{\@gobble}
\makeatother
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{-\baselineskip}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{-\baselineskip}{*0}

\usepackage{fancyhdr, extramarks}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
%\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhead[LE, RO]{\color{\mycolor}\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\color{\mycolor}Academic Calendar}
\fancyhead[LO]{\color{\mycolor}2024-25}
\fancyhead[C]{\color{\mycolor}Odd Semester}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{\headrulewidth}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{{\color{\mycolor}Working days:} \theworkday}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{{\color{\mycolor}Class days:} \theclasses}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{ragged2e}
\parindent0pt
\parskip0pt
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\selectcolormodel{natural}
\usepackage{ninecolors}
\selectcolormodel{cmyk}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\SetTblrInner[tblr]{rowsep=0pt,stretch=0}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\Rownum{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\ifnum\value{magicrownumbers}<10 0\fi\arabic{magicrownumbers}}
\preto\tblr{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}}
\preto\tabular{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}}

%\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
%\newcommand\Rownum{\ifnum\value{rownum}<10 0\fi\arabic{rownum}}
\newcommand\calcrowht{%
    \dimexpr%
    (%
    \textheight%
%   - 0.4pt * ( \value{rowcount} + 1) % hrule sizes
    ) / \value{rowcount}%
    \relax%
}

\newcount\myjdate
\newcount\myweekday
\newcounter{tmpmyjdate}
\newcounter{tmpmyweekday}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}
\def\wday#1{%
    \pgfcalendardatetojulian{#1}{\myjdate}%
    \setcounter{tmpmyjdate}{\the\myjdate}%
    \pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\thetmpmyjdate}{\myweekday}%
    \setcounter{tmpmyweekday}{\the\myweekday}%
    \nwday%
}
\def\nwday{%
    \ifcase\value{tmpmyweekday}Mon\or Tue\or Wed\or Thu\or Fri\or Sat\or Sun\fi\relax%
    \stepcounter{tmpmyjdate}\relax%
    \pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\thetmpmyjdate}{\myweekday}%
    \setcounter{tmpmyweekday}{\the\myweekday}%
}
\newcounter{workday}
\newcounter{classes}
\newcommand\Class{\stepcounter{workday}\stepcounter{classes}Class}
\newcommand\Exam{\stepcounter{workday}\stepcounter{classes}Exam}
\newcommand\adm{\stepcounter{workday}Admission}
\newcommand\SL{\stepcounter{workday}SL}
\preto\tblr{\setcounter{classes}{0}}
\preto\tblr{\setcounter{workday}{0}}

\NewColumnType{A}{%
    >{%
        \raggedleft
        \let\newline\\%
        \arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}%
    }%
    p{0.01\linewidth}%
}
\NewColumnType{B}{%
    >{%
        \raggedleft
        \let\newline\\%
        \arraybackslash
        \hspace{0pt}%
    }%
    p{0.02\linewidth}%
}
\NewColumnType{C}{%
    >{%
        \raggedleft
        \let\newline\\
        \arraybackslash
        \hspace{0pt}%
    }%
    p{0.05\linewidth}%
}
\NewColumnType{D}{%
    >{%
        \raggedleft
        \let\newline\\
        \arraybackslash
        \hspace{0pt}%
    }%
    p{0.85\linewidth}%
}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\C}{\color{\mycolor}}
    \newcommand{\D}{\color{\colour}}
%
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\begin{comment}
%   content

%
\section{July 2024}%
%\subsection{Siliguri}
\begin{tblr}{width=\linewidth, colspec={p{0.01\linewidth} p{0.04\linewidth} p{0.15\linewidth} p{0.7\linewidth}},rows={ht=\calcrowht}}
    \Rownum.    & \wday{2024-07-01} & {\emph{PL}} & \emph{Bana Mahotsav} (NSS)/Preparatory Leave for faculty members\\
    \C\Rownum.  &   \C\nwday\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & \emph{Van Mahotsav} week ends (NSS)\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &SL   & Study Leave for students\\
    \C\Rownum.  &   \C\nwday&   &   15\textsuperscript{th} Foundation Day of the campus\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & IQAC Work\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & IQAC Work\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & Birthday of Fr (Prof) Tomy Augustine, Rector\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & IQAC Work\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & IQAC Work\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &{\emph{PL}}/\Exam & IQAC Work\\
    \C\Rownum.  &   \C\nwday\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & IQAC Work\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & IQAC Work\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & IQAC Work\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & Placement Drive: Indigo/Air India\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & Placement Drive: Indigo/Air India\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &SL/\Exam & Placement Drive: Indigo / Air India / Orientation for Office \& Support Staffs Placement Drive: Indigo / Air India / Orientation for Office \& Support Staffs Placement Drive: Indigo / Air India / Orientation for Office \& Support Staffs\\
    \C\Rownum.  &   \C\nwday&   &   \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & Final Interview: Indigo/Air India\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & IQAC Work\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & IQAC Work\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &Recess & IQAC Work\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &Recess & IQAC Work\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\emph{Hol}     & \textit{Muharram}\\
    \C\Rownum.  &   \C\nwday&   &   \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  & \adm  &   
\end{tblr}
\newpage
\def\mycolor{magenta}
\def\colour{cyan}
\fancyhead[C]{\color{\mycolor}Even Semester}
\section{February '24}%
%\subsection{Siliguri}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={rlll},rows={ht=\calcrowht}}
    \Rownum.    & \wday{2024-02-01} &   \Class  &   Classes resume for Sem II\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &       \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   {\emph{PL}} &   Departmental Picnics\\
    \C\Rownum.    & \C\nwday &  & \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &   Departmental Conference (Physics)\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &   Pass Board Meeting\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &       \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &       \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &   \emph{Technokrat} / Departmental Symposium (Pol Sc) / International Conf' on ECCE (Dept of Education)\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   SL      &   GB Meeting\\
    \C\Rownum.    & \C\nwday &  & \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &       \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &   {\D Publication of SA (Sem I) Results}  \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \emph{Hol}  &   \textit{Saraswati Puja} \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &   Preparations for \emph{Inscape} \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &   \emph{Inscape}  \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   {\emph{PL}} &       \\
    \C\Rownum.    & \C\nwday &  & \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &       \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &       \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &       \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &   Student Seminar (Mass Comm \& Journalism)   \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &   \D Last Day of Application for SA (UG \& PG) Reassessment\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   SL  &       \\
    \C\Rownum.    & \C\nwday &  & \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &   Rector's Cup, Taverna Trophy \& Bishop Marengo Memorial Cup tournaments begin\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &       \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &   Trends in Science \& Technology (TIST) - Day 1\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &   TIST - Day 2 / Forensic Psychology Workshop 
\end{tblr}
%\end{comment}
\end{document}


You can put a \parbox inside a \savebox and measure the total height.  Add \strut at the beginning and end to fill out to \baselineskip.  A more accurate method is to use \setbox\tempbox=\vbox{...} and use \vsplit to 0pt to pull off one line at a time.

@JohnKormylo My sincere apologies to not been able to execute your suggestion. Can you please make it a full answer? Here is the code I am currently stuck with.

Sorry, I don't do PasteBin.  Can you copy and paste it to your question?  (CNTL c and CNTL v for most browsers).

@JohnKormylo I have edited the question with the code. However, out of curiosity, is there a particular reason against using PasteBin? Any risk or dangerous cookie policy that I am unaware of?

I've gotten to the point where I don't register with any new web sites.

This performs each TBLR three times.  The first two runs determines the size of the table as a linear fuction of rowsep.
\documentclass[a5paper, twoside, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[cmyk, table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[margin=20mm, includehead, foot=4mm, marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {/Users/AaRBiTt/OneDrive/Documents/Salesian College/Logos} }
\def\mycolor{cyan}
\def\colour{magenta}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{cmbright}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{}{}{0pt}{\@gobble}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{}{}{0pt}{\@gobble}
\makeatother
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{-\baselineskip}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{-\baselineskip}{*0}

\usepackage{fancyhdr, extramarks}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
%\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhead[LE, RO]{\color{\mycolor}\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\color{\mycolor}Academic Calendar}
\fancyhead[LO]{\color{\mycolor}2024-25}
\fancyhead[C]{\color{\mycolor}Odd Semester}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{\headrulewidth}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{{\color{\mycolor}Working days:} \theworkday}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{{\color{\mycolor}Class days:} \theclasses}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{ragged2e}
\parindent0pt
\parskip0pt
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\selectcolormodel{natural}
\usepackage{ninecolors}
\selectcolormodel{cmyk}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\SetTblrInner[tblr]{rowsep=0pt,stretch=0}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\Rownum{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\ifnum\value{magicrownumbers}<10 0\fi\arabic{magicrownumbers}}
\preto\tblr{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}}
\preto\tabular{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}}

%\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
%\newcommand\Rownum{\ifnum\value{rownum}<10 0\fi\arabic{rownum}}
\newcommand\calcrowht{%
    \dimexpr%
    (%
    \textheight%
%   - 0.4pt * ( \value{rowcount} + 1) % hrule sizes
    ) / \value{rowcount}%
    \relax%
}

\newcount\myjdate
\newcount\myweekday
\newcounter{tmpmyjdate}
\newcounter{tmpmyweekday}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}
\def\wday#1{%
    \pgfcalendardatetojulian{#1}{\myjdate}%
    \setcounter{tmpmyjdate}{\the\myjdate}%
    \pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\thetmpmyjdate}{\myweekday}%
    \setcounter{tmpmyweekday}{\the\myweekday}%
    \nwday%
}
\def\nwday{%
    \ifcase\value{tmpmyweekday}Mon\or Tue\or Wed\or Thu\or Fri\or Sat\or Sun\fi\relax%
    \stepcounter{tmpmyjdate}\relax%
    \pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\thetmpmyjdate}{\myweekday}%
    \setcounter{tmpmyweekday}{\the\myweekday}%
}
\newcounter{workday}
\newcounter{classes}
\newcommand\Class{\stepcounter{workday}\stepcounter{classes}Class}
\newcommand\Exam{\stepcounter{workday}\stepcounter{classes}Exam}
\newcommand\adm{\stepcounter{workday}Admission}
\newcommand\SL{\stepcounter{workday}SL}
\preto\tblr{\setcounter{classes}{0}}
\preto\tblr{\setcounter{workday}{0}}

\NewColumnType{A}{%
    >{%
        \raggedleft
        \let\newline\\%
        \arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}%
    }%
    p{0.01\linewidth}%
}
\NewColumnType{B}{%
    >{%
        \raggedleft
        \let\newline\\%
        \arraybackslash
        \hspace{0pt}%
    }%
    p{0.02\linewidth}%
}
\NewColumnType{C}{%
    >{%
        \raggedleft
        \let\newline\\
        \arraybackslash
        \hspace{0pt}%
    }%
    p{0.05\linewidth}%
}
\NewColumnType{D}{%
    >{%
        \raggedleft
        \let\newline\\
        \arraybackslash
        \hspace{0pt}%
    }%
    p{0.85\linewidth}%
}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\NewEnviron{tblpage}{\SetTblrInner{rowsep=\rowsep}% do not change
  \def\rowsep{0pt}%
  \sbox0{\BODY}%
  \def\rowsep{1ex}%
  \sbox2{\BODY}%
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\rowsep}{(\textheight-\ht0-\dp0)/(\ht2+\dp2-\ht0-\dp0)*1ex}
  \BODY}
  
\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\C}{\color{\mycolor}}
    \newcommand{\D}{\color{\colour}}
%
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\begin{comment}
%   content

%
\section{July 2024}%
%\subsection{Siliguri}
\begin{tblpage}
\begin{tblr}{width=\linewidth, colspec={p{0.01\linewidth} p{0.04\linewidth} p{0.15\linewidth} X}}
    \Rownum.    & \wday{2024-07-01} & {\emph{PL}} & \emph{Bana Mahotsav} (NSS)/Preparatory Leave for faculty members\\
    \C\Rownum.  &   \C\nwday\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & \emph{Van Mahotsav} week ends (NSS)\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &SL   & Study Leave for students\\
    \C\Rownum.  &   \C\nwday&   &   15\textsuperscript{th} Foundation Day of the campus\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & IQAC Work\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & IQAC Work\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & Birthday of Fr (Prof) Tomy Augustine, Rector\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & IQAC Work\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & IQAC Work\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &{\emph{PL}}/\Exam & IQAC Work\\
    \C\Rownum.  &   \C\nwday\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & IQAC Work\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & IQAC Work\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & IQAC Work\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & Placement Drive: Indigo/Air India\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & Placement Drive: Indigo/Air India\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &SL/\Exam & Placement Drive: Indigo / Air India / Orientation for Office \& Support Staffs Placement Drive: Indigo / Air India / Orientation for Office \& Support Staffs Placement Drive: Indigo / Air India / Orientation for Office \& Support Staffs\\
    \C\Rownum.  &   \C\nwday&   &   \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & Final Interview: Indigo/Air India\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & IQAC Work\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\Exam & IQAC Work\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &Recess & IQAC Work\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &Recess & IQAC Work\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &\emph{Hol}     & \textit{Muharram}\\
    \C\Rownum.  &   \C\nwday&   &   \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  & \adm  &   
\end{tblr}
\end{tblpage}
\newpage
\def\mycolor{magenta}
\def\colour{cyan}
\fancyhead[C]{\color{\mycolor}Even Semester}
\section{February '24}%
%\subsection{Siliguri}
\begin{tblpage}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={rllX}}
    \Rownum.    & \wday{2024-02-01} &   \Class  &   Classes resume for Sem II\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &   \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   {\emph{PL}} &   Departmental Picnics\\
    \C\Rownum.    & \C\nwday &  & \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &   Departmental Conference (Physics)\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &   Pass Board Meeting\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &       \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &       \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &   \emph{Technokrat} / Departmental Symposium (Pol Sc) / International Conf' on ECCE (Dept of Education)\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   SL      &   GB Meeting\\
    \C\Rownum.    & \C\nwday &  & \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &       \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &   {\D Publication of SA (Sem I) Results}  \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \emph{Hol}  &   \textit{Saraswati Puja} \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &   Preparations for \emph{Inscape} \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &   \emph{Inscape}  \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   {\emph{PL}} &       \\
    \C\Rownum.    & \C\nwday &  & \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &       \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &       \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &       \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &   Student Seminar (Mass Comm \& Journalism)   \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &   \D Last Day of Application for SA (UG \& PG) Reassessment\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   SL  &       \\
    \C\Rownum.    & \C\nwday &  & \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &   Rector's Cup, Taverna Trophy \& Bishop Marengo Memorial Cup tournaments begin\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &       \\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &   Trends in Science \& Technology (TIST) - Day 1\\
    \Rownum.    &   \nwday  &   \Class  &   TIST - Day 2 / Forensic Psychology Workshop
\end{tblr}
\end{tblpage}
%\end{comment}
\end{document}


Thank you so much for this answer. Though it is not perfect, it certainly is the best solution available in hand. On nitpicking, I observed that whenever a line wraps, the rowsep with the previous row is inconsistently decreased. For instance on the rows of February 8-9, 25-26 and 27-28.

See newer version.

Thank you. This makes it a perfect solution. I am accepting this. A couple of follow-up questions below:


What does environ package bring into plate? Why the native command \newenvironment won't do?



Please explain the algorithm behind the calculations. Specifically, what is \sbox and what is \dp?


The environ package creates environments where the contents are stored in \BODY, making it easy to process them more than once. \sbox and \savebox are basically the same thing, I just use \sbox with registers 0-9 out of habit. Being inside an environment (or group) makes it okay to use local registers. For y=ax+b, b=y(0) and a=(y(1)-y(0))/(1-0). The inverse is x=(y-b)/a=(y-y(0))/(y(1)-y(0)). Oh, and \dp stands for depth (distance from the bottom to the baseline).
